# How to pass a list of lists to CMake macro

Tags: list, parameters, macros, cmake

How can I pass a list of lists to a CMake macro?

If I do

```
MACRO(Exclude_From_List)
  FOREACH(arg ${ARGN})
    MESSAGE(${arg})
  ENDFOREACH()
ENDMACRO()
```

and call it like

```
EXCLUDE_FROM_LIST("${List1}" "${List2}" EXCLUDE "ToRemove")
```

I will lose the lists which I still need after the macro. I just want a list of patterns (in this case ToRemove) beeing removed from every list which contains the entry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you need to pass the list of *list names* into the `macro` rather than the values contained in the lists.

By doing `("${List1}" "${List2}" ...)`, you're creating a single big list of the concatenated contents of `List1` and `List2`.

Your `macro` should be more like this:

```
MACRO(Exclude_From_List)
  # Split inputs into list of list variable names and items to be removed
  SET(FoundExclude FALSE)
  FOREACH(arg ${ARGN})
    IF(FoundExclude)
      LIST(APPEND ToBeRemoved ${arg})
    ELSEIF(${arg} STREQUAL "EXCLUDE")
      SET(FoundExclude TRUE)
    ELSE()
      LIST(APPEND ListNames ${arg})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()

  MESSAGE("Removing ${ToBeRemoved} from lists named ${ListNames}")

  FOREACH(ListName ${ListNames})
    # Ensure the variable is actually valid
    IF(DEFINED ${ListName})
      LIST(REMOVE_ITEM ${ListName} ${ToBeRemoved})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()
ENDMACRO()
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
SET(List1 A B C D E F)
SET(List2 F E D C B A)
SET(List3 1 2 3 4 5 6)
SET(List4 "")
SET(List5)

Exclude_From_List(List1 List2 List3 List4 List5 EXCLUDE A D F)
```